# Fullscreen slider stutters on Webkit, smooth on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, fullscreen

**The problem**

Im using Vegas Slider jQuery plugin (latest), with latest jQuery, based on bootstrap. Background fade animation works perfectly fine on Firefox and IE10, but on Safari, Chrome and Opera is laggy and slow.

I've made a copy here for you to check out, so I don't change enything while waiting for response:

http://8020.pl/web/templates/stackoverflow/

The Vegas slider website is here:

http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Transitions work fine there.

**What i've tried**

Disabled all other javascript (which means basically removing bootstrap js file, so it's not loaded). My main.js contained only vegas js, nothing more.
**result: nothing**

Changed images sizes from ~1080p to 800x450. **result: no change**

Switched all 'fixed' positioning to 'absolute' to check if this is related to well known chrome bug with fixed backgrounds. **result: no change**

I wouldn't even try to fix it as I know chrome is notorious for this kind of behaviour, but it **works on plugin website** and not on mine,so I had to do something wrong, just can't figure it out.

It is important to note, that this occurs when windows is larger than ~1200px wide, so it may be fine on smaller screens.

Thanks.

[edit]

I've concluded that on plugin page the problem appears too (tried resizing window to 3840x1200 - lags badly on chrome, while still being fine on firefox). Is there any way to smooth it out at least a bit on 1080p screens or is it just the way it gies on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I've opened your localhost from my browser (google chrome), and it's switching in the same way as in the plugin homepage. Are you sure in your browser everything is ok? Sometimes loading crashed plugins might cause problems.

Comment: I'm not sure if my browser is ok been using it for some time, but it's mostly noticable in high resolutions (running 1920x1200 here). Client is a photographer, so he's bound to have a big screen, that's why this is even a problem.